# About GCM implementation Android application after April 11, 2019(GCM is abolished)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

In the Firebase console, I selected my GCM project from the list of existing Google Cloud projects, and add Firebase,
and now, even if I update my server code to use new FCM endpoints for sending messages,  Push notification will be sent to the existing GCM version Android application It has arrived.

Will Push notifications be sent to GCM version applications after April 11, 2019(GCM APIs will be removed)?

It seems that such meaning is written in GoogleDeveloper (※ https: //firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html).
But my android app does not use "GcmListenerService" which appears in Google official migration guide.
my android app is an old implementation just after migrating a C2DM Client for GCM Client,
is the old implementation right after moving from C2DM to GCM, is my android app OK?

**Current implementation**

1. Start Service with the intent of
   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER specified, and register
   registration ID
2. Receive BroadCast of com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION,
   obtain registrationId and send it to business server
3. Receive BroadCast of com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE,
   receive push notification from the server.

For business reasons,
It is difficult to forcibly update the current user's Android application from the GCM version to the FCM version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the same [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you have projects that are still using the GCM APIs, you will need to update ***your client*** and server code to use FCM before April 11, 2019.

With that, it seems you need to update the client app as well. There isn't any documentation that says that app versions that are still using GCM code would cease to receive messages, but the behavior to receive will no longer be guaranteed after the said date.

Business wise, you may not force the update, but make it so that users are encouraged to update by saying something along the lines of "*An update is necessary to use the full potential of the app.*"

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following conclusion, based on this (from further down the same [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html)):

> **What happens to my users who don't update their apps?**
>
> As long as users have GCM logic in their apps, they will still receive messages. FCM is backwards compatible with GCM, so even if you don't update your server endpoint now, you can still update your app's logic, and vice versa.

And from the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq):

> Note that client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work indefinitely. However, you won't be able to target the latest version of Google Play Services in your Android app unless you migrate to FCM.

So I'm going to play it safe and have both my server and app updated with FCM before the deadline.

But to answer your question, users who have not upgraded to the FCM version of the app should still continue to receive push notifications after the April 2019 deadline.